# Number of arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Problem: What is the formula of number of arrangements? More specifically I need to avoid repeated elements and the order of the sequence does not matter. For lucidity I show an example:
For 3 elements:
1
2
3

1 2 
1 3 
2 4 

1 2 3

For 4 elements:

1
2
3
4

1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3

1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4

1 2 3 4

I really don't know the mathematical name of this arranging, I suppose the form of this is *((n-1)*n)+1*. So what is this exactly?

Comment: It is $2^n-1$, because for each number up to $n$, there are two possibilities and you want at least one number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the number of non-empty **subsets** of a set. If the set has $n$ elements, it has $2^n-1$ non-empty subsets.

Imagine that the elements of the set are lined up in a row. To make a subset, we say "yes" or "no" to each of the elements.  There are $2^n$ ways to do this, but one of them (all no) produces the empty set.

The number of $k$ element subsets pf a set of $m$ elements is often denoted by $\binom{n}{k}$.  It turns out that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

**Remark:** So for example the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ has $2^4-1=15$ non-empty subsets. The list in the OP has $13$. because $\{2,4\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ are missing.